# Android set alarm with an unique id

Tags: java, android

In my application I am using multiple Alarm manger and they all are working fine. Now I need two more things in my app:

- Set an ID for each alarmManager so I can identify this alarm in my broadcast receiver
- use this id to cancel alarm later

**My code for Setting Alarm**

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h1);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m1+30);
    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);


    // Add Some unique ID here for e.g "SFSF43535"
    PendingIntent openAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     // Add Some unique ID here for e.g "SFSf87sfs"
    PendingIntent CloseAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                      cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, openAlarm);

   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                      cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, CloseAlarm);
```

**YourBroadCastReceiver** (here I need that unique ID)

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // Get Unique id here to find some data related to that alram 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extras to your `Intent` which will get passed along:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("id", "somerandomID");
```

And then get the extra back in the receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: but this intent will be same for all PendingIntent so this will not work for multiple   Alarm

Comment: i have edited my code now you can see how will i set multiple alarms using same Intent

Comment: Create two different Intents for different PendingIntent

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intentOpen = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
    intentOpen.putExtra("id", 1);
    PendingIntent openAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentOpen, 0);

    Intent intentClose = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
    intentClose.putExtra("id", 2);
    PendingIntent CloseAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentClose, 0);
```

and on Received

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      int AlarmId = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
      if(AlarmId==1)
      {
      }else if(AlarmId==2)
      {
          //Cancle
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            AlarmId, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    pendingIntent.cancel();
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
      }
}
```